# Issue Preparing iPhone 7 (iOS 15.7.7) for Development Using Xcode 14.3.1 on MacBook Air M1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm facing a persisting issue with my iPhone 7 (running iOS 15.7.7) when trying to use it for testing an app through Xcode 14.3.1 on my MacBook Air M1. The issue arises after I connect the iPhone and confirm trust for the device. In Xcode's Devices and Simulators, I constantly see the message "iPhone is busy: Preparing iPhone for development".

I understand that this is a common issue that many have faced, but I've tried all suggested solutions such as restarting both devices, buying a new cable, unpairing and re-pairing, among others. All the solutions that I've found online have not worked for me and this issue has been persisting for several days now.

One peculiar observation I made is that there are always two "Making iPhone ready for developing" messages appearing simultaneously. I've tried cancelling these processes in case they are stuck in a deadlock but I've been unsuccessful in finding a way to do this.

[image]

I also have questions regarding Xcode's compatibility with iOS versions. The information available does not clearly state the minimum iOS version supported for working with an external device using Xcode. I also noticed that newer iOS versions have a "Developer Mode", but I understand that my current version may not support it. I would like to know what the recommended version of Xcode would be for working with an iPhone 7.

I appreciate any advice or suggestions you may have. Thank you.

Comment: Connecting a device can take à very long time and I couldn’t figure out what happened. You can check in organiser /device and simulator /your iPhone /device logs when the last fix loaded crash log are from. As the version is a 3 numbers version the complete package can take 1GB of data to load which is very long with lightning /wifi